# IEEE 754 floating point number symbol

Tags: numerical-methods, notation

There are symbols for real numbers, natural numbers, integer numbers ($\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}$) and so on. Is there any symbol to denote IEEE 754 floating point number? I would find this useful when dealing with computer graphics, where coordinates aren't really in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but rather something like $(IEE 754\; floating\; point)^3$.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of; this isn't really something mathematical. In practice, you can just write something like, "Let $A$ denote the set of IEEE754 floating point numbers, and let $x\in A^3$." You'd need to specify the operations on $A$, depending on your audience, and it's probably not going to have any useful structure (e.g., of a group, ring, field, etc.) because of under-/overflow and finite precision. If it's just for a technical document, you can denote floating point numbers the same way you'd denote any other kind of class, object, etc.

Comment: Elaborating on @anomaly's comment:  the IEEE 754 standards describe a number of different formats (differing by base, by precision) and number of different definitions of the operators (because of different round-off rules).  So there cannot be _one_  unambiguous symbol here.

Comment: @kimchilover I guess you could have some subscript system for this, but thanks I get the message.